# Unable to save filter to mobile folder

Tags: android

I am trying to save file which is working on emulator but as i am attaching my mobile and trying to save the image file then it gives error..

This is my MainActivity.java file

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView myimageView;
    Button btn_save;

    BitmapDrawable drawable;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    File sdcard;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myimageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        btn_save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myBtn);

        btn_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawable = (BitmapDrawable)myimageView.getDrawable();
                bitmap=drawable.getBitmap();
                FileOutputStream outputStream=null;

                sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File directory = new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath()+"/Demo");
                directory.mkdir();
                String filename = String.format("%d.jpg",System.currentTimeMillis());
                File outFile = new File(directory,filename);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Image saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                try {
                    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,outputStream);
                    outputStream.flush();
                    outputStream.close();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                    intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(outFile));
                    sendBroadcast(intent);

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

the error is ,

```
W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:252)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7309)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:482)
        ... 14 more
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Demo/1594279584750.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:235)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:186)
```

i just need to save an image in my mobile folder in the format as **/internal_storage/Download/image/imagename.jpg**

Comment: `directory.mkdir();` Only call mkdir if the directory does not exist yet. And then check the return value as it might fail to create the directory. In that case display a toast to inform the user. And return as continuing makes things only worse. Please adapt your code. Here too.

Comment: `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Image saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` That toast is much to early. There is not even a stream opened yet. Please adapt your code. Here too.

Comment: `/internal_storage/Download/image/imagename.jpg` That is a non existing path. As a programmer you talk about `/storage/emulated/0/Demo/1594279584750.jpg` as you can see in the log you posted.